# Spring Boot compatibility with Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a Spring Cloud config server running under release train Dalston.SR4.  It has been in production for a few years serving config to some older Spring Boot apps.  Today I'm trying to build a new Spring Boot 2.3.0 app.  When my app starts up and tries to fetch its configuration from the config server, the config server just returns a 406 Not Acceptable.  I can successfully browse to the config URL my app is trying to fetch from and see the config in my browser, so I'm just wondering if this is a case of version compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is!

> Greenwich builds and works with Spring Boot 2.1.x, and is not expected to work with Spring Boot 1.5.x.
>
> Note: The Dalston release train will reach end-of-life in December 2018. Edgware will follow the end-of-life cycle of Spring Boot 1.5.x.
>
> *The Dalston and Edgware release trains build on Spring Boot 1.5.x, and are not expected to work with Spring Boot 2.0.x.*

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions

Answer (score 0):

The next planned Spring Cloud `Hoxton` release train release, `Hoxton.SR5` will be coming with Spring Boot `2.3.0` support this month. You will need to upgrade to that release in order to maintain compatibility with Spring Boot. Alternatively, the `2020.0.0` release trains also offers Spring Boot `2.3.0` support, but there's not GA release within that train available yet.

Answer (score 0):

Note the table on the https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud page:
[image: Release train Spring Boot compatibility table]

Also note that some of the starters [were renamed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes#renamed-starters) in Edgware release train. So it makes sense to read all the release notes of the intermediate release trains between your current version and the version you are going to update to.